# Can I call Yahoo Weather API from local js file? Or do I need a web server?

Tags: javascript, yahoo, weather-api, yahoo-weather-api

Yahoo Weather API now requires an OAuth1 signature. Can I do a normal AJAX GET call from a local html file to retrieve Weather data or do I have to call it from a web server? This is for a local HTML widget I’m creating for my desktop computer and I do not want to get a web server for this only purpose.

If it doesn’t work, I will move to OpenWeatherMap or Weatherbit.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get a CORS error so you need to call it from server side. I don't know if OpenWeatherMap or Weatherbit will cause CORS error, but if you do get an error and don't really wanna make web server, use firebase cloud functions and call it using simple javascript http request. it's easy to setup firebase and you don't really make server code. Hope this helps

Comment: OpenWeatherMap and Weatherbit won’t make a CORS error. DarkSky will make an error but if you use a proxy server such as https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com, you can bypass the CORS error. I’m using Weatherbit now.